# PowerBI: Using a service principal to update a dataset

Tags: azure, rest, powerbi

I'm trying to push data to a PowerBI online dataset, to automatically update financial dashboards for our company.

Here's where we stand:

- We have PowerBI pro accounts with a few dashboards, reports and datasets published internally.
- We have an Azure account and the possiblity to create whatever we need in there

After reading a whole lot of (sometimes contradictory) documentation, here's what I think I want:

- setup a cron job to update datasets nightly
- use the PowerBI Rest API to update the datasets that were published by the analysts
- use a service principal to authenticate against that API
- ideally, use the C# (or typescript?) library to interact with the API, although not strictly necessary

Here's, in no particular order, some of the doc pages I've been through:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/automation/walkthrough-push-data
- https://powerbi.microsoft.com/nl-be/blog/use-power-bi-api-with-service-principal-preview/
- https://github.com/Microsoft/PowerBI-CSharp#usage-calling-the-getreports-api
- and so many others I've lost track of.

I'm not familiar with Azure, so I may be missing key background knowledge, but I can't, for the life of me, figure out how to setup and use this api with a service principal...

...

Please send help!

Comment: It looks like you are trying to use Power BI as a database. You shouldn't. Store the data somewhere else, in a real database. Then make a Power BI report using this database as a datasource and update the data there. Then you can use the API to tell the report's dataset to refresh itself (which is easy to be done with a service principal)

Comment: Definitely not using PowerBI as a database (data comes from other SaaS), but this specific use case is one they advertise in their documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/automation/walkthrough-push-data And in any case, I still need to figure ou how to use a service principal.

Comment: This one is a push dataset, which is completely different case that the one I described. With push datasets, there is no underlying database, but you have to push the data through the API or something else (e.g. PubNub)

Comment: Pushing data through the API is my plan indeed. Are you saying I'm misunderstanding concepts here?

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant when I say that you are trying to use it as a database. If you do that, you wont be able to delete some of the rows (only to delete all of them) and also there is a limit of rows (200k or 5M - see [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/automation/api-rest-api-limitations)) and if you reach this limit you will have a lots of fun

Comment: Oh, I see... That's pretty bad, thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: Though in our case I don't think we will hit those limits, so I'll keep the question open. However I'm also interested in pointers on how we could use an external database as you suggested!

Comment: The github repo you linked is a C# library repo specific to Power BI Embedded, which does not cover most of their REST API. As of today, I believe you are left on your own as far as Microsoft provided libraries that serve as a wrapper for the majority of the Power BI REST API functionality. Also if your SaaS supports Azure AD you should look in to [managed identities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/overview). Otherwise you appear to be on the right track.

Comment: If you end up moving away from a push dataset, Power BI service does include some limited scheduling functionality as well. So if all you need is to schedule a periodic refresh, then you can avoid some custom development and use their built in scheduling. Just a thought.

Comment: That's good to know. Might actually be the way we're going, after all of these discussions. Big SQL database with some kind of automatic refresh from PBI side. Thanks for the input.